# How do I create a developer account in paypal - is it same as business account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am creating an asp.net site to interact with Paypal.  To see if my code works, I want to use the PayPal sandbox.  I read that the steps are:

1. Establish a developer account on Developer central (developer.paypal.com)
   but when I go there and click on "sign up", it seems to be creating a "business account" instead.
2. Also, it says to create a personal account on the sandbox.  Can (or should) this have the same email address as the developer account?
3. I also have a personal (non-sandbox) paypal account I've been using for years - should I avoid using the email address that I use for that account with the developer account?
4. I read that I should create a business account on the sandbox.    Does that use the same address as the personal account for the sandbox?  (or as as the developer account)

(The instructions I'm looking at are at:
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/sell/ipn-test-outside)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1 & #3 -- If your existing account is a business account, yes go ahead and use it for creating your developer account. Or if it's a personal account, pick a different email address to use just for your business account and use that when you log in to developer.paypal.com

## 2 & #4 -- Creating a Sandbox account is different. You will do this within Developer Central once you are logged in.  You can makeup a fake email address for this, I recommend not using a real email address.